# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Twig_Autoloader' not found

Tags: php, twig, fatal-error, templating, templating-engine

Recently I installed Twig2.0 via Composer for PHP7.2 and when running the code I'm getting these errors,

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Twig_Autoloader' not found
> in C:\wamp64\www\php-twig\example.php on line 4
>
> ( ! ) Error: Class 'Twig_Autoloader' not found in C:\wamp64\www\php-twig\example.php on line 4

I go through the issues in GitHub.

Here is my PHP code,

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');

$options = array(
    'name' => 'Sumithran',
);

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, $options);
```

And index.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Twig test</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    
    <p>And hello {{ name }}</p>
    
</body>
</html>
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

`Twig_Autoloader` was deprecated in version 1.21. You are using version 2.0, so you must use:

```
$loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader('templates');

$options = array(
    'name' => 'Sumithran',
);

$twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader, $options);
```

More details at [Twig Docs - Twig for Developers](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#twig-for-developers).

Answer (score 1):

Twig version 2+ introduced the use of **namespaces** and the class-structure is a bit different now.

For instance instead of in `Twig_Loader_Filesystem` the filesystem-loader is located at `Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader`.

You can also use [rector](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector) to change all the namespaces to version 2 at once.

Tomas Votruba describes the process more detailed in this [blog-post](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2019/04/04/how-to-upgrade-twig-from-underscored-to-namespaces/).

**TLDR; - Run the following commands to upgrade to namespaces seamlessly.**

```
composer require rector/rector --dev # make sure you have version 0.4.10+ at least
vendor/bin/rector process src --level twig-underscore-to-namespace
```

Comment: If you're using PhpStorm or a similar IDE you can also use autocomplete.